# Unable to fetch Wi-Fi list in Android 11 Lenovo Tablet

Tags: java, android-wifi, android-11

Basically, I'm trying to show **available Wi-Fi** list in my **Lenovo-Tablet Android 11**, but it's **not working**. The same code is working fine for **BMAX-Tablet Android 11** and I can see the list.
Here is the code, that is working fine for **BMAX-Tablet Android 11** but not for the **Lenovo-Tablet Android 11**.

```
public class WifiConnectionActivity extends ThermalogBaseActivity implements 
WifiItemListener {

private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
private static final String TAG = WifiConnectionActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
List<ScanResult> list;
ProgressDialog dialog;
RecyclerView wifiRecyclerView;
WifiAdapter wifiAdapter;
private WifiManager wifiManager;
private WifiBroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_connection);
    disableButtonsSettings();

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(WifiConnectionActivity.this);
    this.wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    checkPermission();

    wifiRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.wifi_recycler_view);
    wifiRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(WifiConnectionActivity.this));
    wifiRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

}

void checkPermission() {
    dialog.setTitle("Loading");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.show();
    int permission1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    // Check for permissions
    if (permission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Permissions");

        // Request permissions
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
                }, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
        dialog.dismiss();
        return;
    }
    wifiManager.startScan();
}

void showAvailableWifiList(List<ScanResult> list) {
    wifiAdapter = new WifiAdapter(WifiConnectionActivity.this, list, this::getItemPosition);
    wifiRecyclerView.setAdapter(wifiAdapter);
    wifiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission Granted: " + permissions[0]);
                // Start Scan Wifi.
                wifiManager.startScan();
            } else {
                // Permission denied, Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission Denied: " + permissions[0]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    wifiReceiver = new WifiBroadcastReceiver(wifiManager);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, intentFilter);
}


// Define class to listen to broadcasts
class WifiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    WifiManager wifiManager;

    public WifiBroadcastReceiver(WifiManager wifiManager) {
        this.wifiManager = wifiManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean isUpdated = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false);
        if (isUpdated) {
            // dialog.show(AdminSettingsActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
            list = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            showAvailableWifiList(list);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Scan not OK");
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

}
```

I'm not getting any error in case of **Lenovo-Tablet Android 11**.
How can I resolve this?

**Solution:
Enable tablet location.**

Comment: Just to be sure: Can you please confirm that the Lenovo tablet WiFi is turned on and working correctly, specifically that you can see a list of available networks from the android settings. You might want to check permissions before you attempt to get the WiFi list.

Comment: Lenovo tablet Wi-Fi is turned on and working correctly, and I have also accepted the Permissions.

Comment: It's not showing available Wi-Fi list.